# JavaScript - How to calculate the distance from max value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I currently have a problems counting the distance between the max value and other values in array. Basically I want to make a new array where the values will be the distances from the max value. What I mean by this:

##### Example

I have an array of objects:

```
var array = [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: 20,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        value: 2,
      },
    ];

}]
```

I want the result of this new algorithm that I am trying to make to be like this:

##### Result

```
var newArray = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Reason for this are the distance between the max value and other **values** that we have. The values that are same needs to have the same distance. Max value is 20 so it needs to have 0 as a result, 10 is second value and it is 1 distance away from max value and so on.

What should I do to start working on this?

Comment: what do you mean by `distance`? The number of unique values between the max and itself ?

Comment: Yes! You are right, I forgot to explain that but that is it

Comment: 1. extract all the values and sort them (& remove duplicates).  2. The index in the sorted set is the distance of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case your array is already sorted:

```js
var array = [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: 20,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        value: 2,
      },
    ];


const order = new Set(array.map(el => el.value))

const res = array.map(el => [...order].indexOf(el.value))

console.log(res)
```

in case you need to sort the array before:

```js
var array = [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: 20,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        value: 2,
      },
    ];

const sortedArray = array.sort((a,b) => a.value >= b.value ? -1 : 1)

const order = new Set(sortedArray.map(el => el.value))

const res = sortedArray.map(el => [...order].indexOf(el.value))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: You probably want to convert `order` into an array once up front rather than on every `map` callback.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array with just the **unique** values, **sorted** from high to low
2. Map over the `array` and get the index of that value in the array from step-1

```js
var array = [{id: 1, value: 20, }, {id: 2, value: 10, }, {id: 3, value: 10, }, {id: 4, value: 3, }, {id: 5, value: 2, }, ];

var vals = array.map(a => a.value)
                .filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i)
                .sort((a, b) => b - a);
                
var res = array.map(v => vals.indexOf(v.value));

console.log(res); // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one doesn't care whether the array is originally sorted; as it starts by sorting a shallow copy.

```js
const positions = (xs, ys = [...xs] .sort ((a, b) => b .value - a .value)) =>
  xs .map (x => ys .findIndex (y => x .value == y.value))

const array1 = [{id: 1, value: 20}, {id: 2, value: 10}, {id: 3, value: 10}, {id: 4, value: 3}, {id: 5, value: 2}]
const array2 = [{id: 1, value: 10}, {id: 2, value: 10}, {id: 3, value: 20}, {id: 4, value: 3}, {id: 5, value: 2}]

console .log (positions (array1))
console .log (positions (array2))
```

Then all we do is map our inputs to find the index of the first object in the sorted version that has the same `value`.